# Regularexpression C# how to

Tags: c#, regex

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count = 0;
            String s = "writeln('Helloa a') tung ('main')";
            String patern = @"\'+[\S+\s]*\'";
            Regex myRegex = new Regex(patern);
            foreach (Match regex in myRegex.Matches(s)) {
                Console.WriteLine(regex.Value.ToString());
            }

        }
```

When run, it show

```
'Helloa a') tung ('main'
```

I want not to this

I want to it print

```
'Helloa a'
'main'
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

try using this regexp:

```
@"\'[^']+\'"
```

It will print:

```
'Helloa a'
'main'
```

Answer (score 1):

add a `?` after the `*` to make the `*` non-greedy

```
@"\'+[\S+\s]*?\'"
```

http://rubular.com/r/tso5Uvc88v

---

**REGEXPLANATION:**

A **greedy** regex operator will take the largest possible string that it can(between 2 single quotes which in your case is the bolded part.

> writeln('**Helloa a') tung ('main**')

a non-greedy operator will take the smallest possible section, which is what you wanted.

to make a `+` or `*` non-greedy, just put a `?` after it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lazy quantifier. Replace `*` by `*?` as Sam I am suggests it, or use this solution:

```
@"\'(?>[^']+|(?<=\\)')*\'"
```

that allows escaped quotes.

Details

```
(?>           open an atomic group
    [^']+     all that is not a quote one or more times
   |          OR
    (?<=\\)'  a quote preceded by a backslash
)             close the atomic group
*             repeat the group zero or more times
```

More informations about atomic groups [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html).

Answer (score 0):

I take it you only want to capture anything within the quotes and parentheses? Try this: `\(\'(.+?)\'\)`